# Anime where the main character was saved by the school president and after a train crash he awakens his power

Tags: story-identification, anime

It is a fantasy anime; the main character is a boy who was saved from his school that was attacked by monsters. He was a candidate as wielder of the power of an old hero that protected. After the train crash he awakened his powers and noone knew who was the hero he took power from, so they headed to this academy.

Also his hand was turned into a harpoon when he used the hero's power.
Its not angel beats

I remember he was clone that was created from the villain he had brown hair he maid the contract with the hero through a card i also remember tha the school president had a cat in the dorms even though no pets were allowed i know its not much of a help but thats all i remember now if I remember something new i will update this post

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Angel Beats starts with a train crash and everyone is able to manifest sword-blades from their hands; https://youtu.be/mpl9Gtk8MOc

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any of the details of the main character's appearance?  Was it in colour?

Comment: @Valorum I don't think this is Angel Beats. There's no "old hero", the train crash *kills* the protagonist (and isn't shown until about Episode 9), and only Kanade/Angel can turn her arms into blades, as far as I can recall.

Comment: Its not angel beats

Comment: I remember he was clone that was created from the villain he had brown hair he maid the contract with the hero through a card thats all i remember right now

Comment: In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this?

Comment: i watched it between 2020 and 2021

Comment: Talk of hero clones and contract cards makes me think of UQ Holder.

Comment: Unfortunately its not uq holder

Answer (score 1):

Is it Seven knights revolution: Hero Successor?

After the train is attacked and derailed the Mc and school president(female) fight the physis. When the she runs out of options the Mc pleads with a goddess for the power to save her. It comes in the form of a silver card that allows him to use succession. Succession is using the power of a hero in history, the Mc is the form a armored arm that fires a harpoon. The president is later revealed to be taking care of a stray cat in secret at the student concel dorm.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct anime, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.